# Plugin relations design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I want to build plugin system for a app

```
Site.first.plugins #=> [ 
#<Plugin id: 1, site_id: 1, plugin_type: "Plugin::GoogleAnalityc", created_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19", updated_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19">, 
#<Plugin id: 1, site_id: 1, plugin_type: "Plugin::GoogleAdwords", created_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19", updated_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19">
] # and onther classes with its own implementations
```

so i have model relations like this:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plugins
end

class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  # there's starts my problem
  # I need that class will be defined dynamicly
  # to achive turned on plugin
  has_many :plugin_types, class_name: self.plugin_type
end

class Plugin::GoogleAnalityc < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plugin
end
```

thus i would have

```
Site.first.plugins # list of all turned on plugins
Site.first.plugins.first.plygin_types # => [
#<Plugin::GoogleAnalitycs id: 1, plugin_id: 1, key: 'counterID', value: '1234567', created_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19", updated_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19">,
#<Plugin::GoogleAnalitycs id: 1, plugin_id: 1, key: 'targetID', value: '87654321', created_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19", updated_at: "2014-06-06 08:34:19">
]
```

Could you advise a design implementation for the plugin system if me\you dont't know what plugin will be needed tommorow?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your code, you're best using [**STI (Single Table Inheritance)**](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance):

```
#app/models/site.rb
Class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :plugins #-> will return plugins, which you can filter by type & call custom methods for
end

#need join table - plugins_sites
plugin_id | site_id

#app/models/plugin.rb
class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
  #fields - id | type | your | attributes | created_at | updated_at
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
end

#app/models/plugins/google_analytics.rb
Class GoogleAnalytics < Plugin
   # ... custom stuff here
end

#app/models/plugins/wordpress.rb
Class Wordpress < Plugin
   # ... custom stuff here
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@site = Site.find 1
@site.plugins.each do |plugin|
   plugin.type #=> "GoogleAnalytics"
end
```